# jQuery sparklines set colour of individual bar

Tags: jquery, bar-chart, sparklines

I am using [jquery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) to make cute little bar graphs however I want to only colour the *last* bar a different colour. The code below works, but it would be nice if I could colour the bars by the tooltip names rather than by value.

Is there a way to do that?

```js
var values = [500, 400, 700, 900, 1200, 300, 550];
var dates = {};
var now = new Date();

var counter = 0;
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var d = moment(now).subtract(1 * i, "day").format("MMM DD");
  dates[counter] = d;
  counter++;
}

$("#bargraph1").sparkline(values, {
  type: "bar",
  barWidth: 20,
  barSpacing: 3,
  height: 100,
  tooltipFormat: "<span style=\"color: {{color}}\">&#9679;</span> {{offset:names}} ({{value}})",
  tooltipValueLookups: {
    names: dates
  },
  colorMap: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red"]
});
```

```css
.jqstooltip {
  border: none !important;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<span id="bargraph1"></span>
```

EDIT: can never get the code snippets to work. Heres a fiddle.js : http://jsfiddle.net/wm98qfdb/

Comment: The question was how do I colour the bars by name. So if I have a bar named "Squirrels" how could I colour it green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet, I am bad at pasting the code as well, so... here goes nothing. I didn't implement it, but you could use a case statement in a for-loop to populate an array of names, so that 'squirrel' is always green, etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/omikey/y83dmusn/

```
.jqstooltip {
    border:none !important;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}

var values = [500, 400, 700, 900, 1200, 300, 550];
var dates = {};
var now = new Date();

var counter = 0;
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var d = moment(now).subtract(1 * i, "day").format("MMM DD");
    dates[counter] = d;
    counter++;
}

$("#bargraph1").sparkline(values, {
    type: "bar",
    barWidth: 20,
    barSpacing: 3,
    height: 100,
    tooltipFormat: "<span style=\"color: {{color}}\">&#9679;</span> {{offset:names}} ({{value}})",
            tooltipValueLookups: {
            names: {
                0: 'Squirrel',
                1: 'Kitty',
                2: 'Bird',
                3: 'Three',
                4: 'Four',
                5: 'Five',
                6: 'Six',
                7: 'Seven'
                // Add more here
            }},
    colorMap: ["green", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red"]
});

<span id="bargraph1"></span>
```

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me I could just find out what array item the last value is and repeat the default colour until said index. DOH!